# Navigating to prev slide by button or keyboard not working with free mode Swiper React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js

[image]

**Swiper Free Mode bug**

I'm working on a React project where I'm using Swiper (version ^10.2.0) in free mode for a carousel component. The carousel should allow users to freely drag to scroll through slides and use navigation arrows for moving to the next or previous slides. The next arrow works as expected, but I'm facing an issue with the previous navigation: when I drag the carousel to move forward and then click the previous arrow, it unexpectedly scrolls all the way back to the first slide instead of moving to the immediately preceding slide.

The previous navigation works if you go forwards first with the next arrow/keyboard.

Here's a brief outline of my setup:

Swiper Configuration: Free mode is enabled, and I'm using custom navigation buttons.

**Expected Behavior**: After dragging the carousel forward, clicking the previous arrow should move to the previous slide index based on the current position.

**Actual Behavior**: Clicking the previous arrow scrolls the carousel back to the first slide, ignoring the current slide index.
I've tried debugging and adding event listeners to track the slide index, but nothing has led me to a solution. It seems like something might be overriding the expected behavior, but I can't pinpoint the cause.

I've checked the realIndex and it does correctly update as I drag through the carousel, and I've managed to fully override the prev button like this

`swiperInstance.slideTo(slideIndex - 1, 300);`

But it just seems a bit hacky and overcomplicating it, when it should just work like the next arrow does.

Thanks